# How to group values in a column (R)

Tags: r, grouping, country-codes

I'm creating a summary table that groups my records by country of destination:

```
SummarybyLocation <- PSTNRecords %>% 
                           group_by(Destination) %>%
                                summarize(
                                  Calls = n(), 
                                  Minutes = sum(durationMinutes), 
                                  MaxDuration = max(durationMinutes),
                                  AverageDuration = mean(durationMinutes), 
                                  Charges = sum(charge),
                                  Fees = sum(connectionCharge)
                                )

SummarybyLocation
```

The resulting table is as follows:

[image: Summarized table]

I realized that the Destination values are inconsistent (for example,  "France" and "FR" both refer to the same area, and then I have a "North America" that I presume gathers USA and Canada.

I was wondering if there's a way of creating custom groups for these values, so that the aggregation would make more sense. I tried to use the *countrycode* package to add an iso2c column, but that doesn't resolve the problem of managing other area aggregations like "North America".

I would really appreciate some suggestions on how to handle this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are answering yourself here with that pic. According to it, there are only 16 rows, and there is just one country code "FR". If that data frame is fed by more values to that column in the future, then you have to pay attention. If not, just merge FR and France, North America with Canada and United States.

Comment: You can list all distinct values in `Destination` variable and clean the data prior to summarization.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions! Very useful to have alternative approaches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility for cleaning up the data with a very minimal example. First, I get a list of country names and the 2 and 3 letter abbreviations, and put into a dataframe, `countries`. Then, I `left_join` `countries` to `df` for the two letter code, which in this case matches `FR`. Then, I repeat the `left_join` but with the 3 letter code, which has no matches in this case. Then, I `coalesce` the two new columns together, i.e., `Country.x` and `Country.y`. Then, I use `case_when` to multiple if-else statements. First, if `Country` is not an NA, then I replace `Destination` with the full country name. This is where you can add in other arguments if you have other items (e.g., Europe) that you might also need to fix. Next, I replace `North America` with "United States-Canada-Mexico". Finally, I remove the columns that start with "Country".

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rlist)
library(tidyverse)

theurl <-
  getURL("https://www.iban.com/country-codes",
         .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
countries <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
countries <-
  list.clean(countries, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)[[1]]


df %>%
  left_join(.,
            countries %>% select(Country, `Alpha-2 code`),
            by = c("Destination" = "Alpha-2 code")) %>%
  left_join(.,
            countries %>% select(Country, `Alpha-3 code`),
            by = c("Destination" = "Alpha-3 code")) %>%
  mutate(
    Country = coalesce(Country.x, Country.y),
    Destination = case_when(!is.na(Country) ~ Country,
                            Destination == "North America" ~ "United States-Canada-Mexico",
                            TRUE ~ Destination
  )) %>%
select(-c(starts_with("Country")))
```

**Output**

```
                  Destination durationMinutes charge connectionCharge
1                      France            6.57   0.00                0
2                      France            3.34   1.94                0
3               United States          234.40   3.00                0
4 United States-Canada-Mexico           23.40   2.00                0
```

However, if you have a lot of different variations, then you probably just want to create a simple dataframe with the substitutions, as then you can just do one `left_join`.

Another option is to also add in a Continent column, which you could get from `countrycode`.

```
library(countrycode)

countrycode(sourcevar = df$Destination,
            origin = "country.name",
            destination = "continent")

[1] NA         "Europe"   "Americas" NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Destination = c("FR", "France", "United States", 
"North America"), durationMinutes = c(6.57, 3.34, 234.4, 23.4
), charge = c(0, 1.94, 3, 2), connectionCharge = c(0, 0, 0, 0
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Hi, I really like this approach... this dataset is relatively small, but I will have to use this script for much larger databases and I would like something that automates the process as much as possible and allow for an easy management of the variations. Thanks a lot for the full demo!

Answer (score 1):

The `{countrycode}` package can deal with custom names/codes easily...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(countrycode)

PSTNRecords <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Destination,    ~durationMinutes, ~charge, ~connectionCharge,
  "FR",            1,                2.5,     0.3,
  "France",        1,                2.5,     0.3,
  "United States", 1,                2.5,     0.3,
  "USA",           1,                2.5,     0.3,
  "North America", 1,                2.5,     0.3
)

# see what special codes/country names you have to deal with
iso3cs <- countrycode(PSTNRecords$Destination, "country.name", "iso3c", warn = FALSE)
unique(PSTNRecords$Destination[is.na(iso3cs)])
#> [1] "FR"            "North America"

# decde how to deal with them
custom_matches <- c("FR" = "FRA", "North America" = "USA")

# use your custom codes
PSTNRecords %>%
  mutate(iso3c = countrycode(Destination, "country.name", "iso3c", custom_match = custom_matches))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   Destination   durationMinutes charge connectionCharge iso3c
#>   <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 FR                          1    2.5              0.3 FRA  
#> 2 France                      1    2.5              0.3 FRA  
#> 3 United States               1    2.5              0.3 USA  
#> 4 USA                         1    2.5              0.3 USA  
#> 5 North America               1    2.5              0.3 USA
```

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the countrycode package and that's for sure useful to my end! Is there any other package that would handle for example continents and groups of countries belonging to these continents based on some standard classification?

Comment: The thing about "regions" and "continents" is that there is no definitive definition what those are/mean. `{countrycode}` does have a "many-to-one" `continent` mapping, as well as a few very common regional mappings (e.g. `un.region.name`), but we have strongly resisted adding more because it opens up an infinite rabbit hole. You can see all the mappings supported here: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/countrycode/reference/codelist.html

I also have an unreleased package that does organizational (not spatial/geographical) group mappings: https://github.com/cjyetman/memberstates

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps!